# Cannot Authorise the request to get file's meta-data from Google Drive REST API

Tags: ios, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-client

I need to get the file's metadata, so I am referring https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get

This requires the fileId which I have, but it also requires the **apiKey**.

I figured out that apiKey is coming from GTLServiceDrive object, which is responsible for authorisation.

In ViewController.h file

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) GTLServiceDrive *service;
```

In ViewController.m file

```
- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController
  finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)authResult
             error:(NSError *)error {
if (error != nil) {
    [self showAlert:@"Authentication Error" message:error.localizedDescription];
    self.service.authorizer = nil;
}
else {
    self.service.authorizer = authResult;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

     [self fetchFiles];
}
```

}

But self.service.APIKey is coming **nil** . Therefore, i could not request

**GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{myFileId_string}?key={YOUR_API_KEY}**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stack: please add the code that you are having a problem with and any errors it is returning.    Also please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You do NOT need an apiKey.

What you do need is an Access Token. I've never programmed iOS so can't be much help, but Googling "google oauth ios" should throw up some resources.

Comment: on giving the 'access-token', throws the error response: 
{
error: {
errors: [1]
0:  {
domain: "global"
reason: "required"
message: "Login Required"
locationType: "header"
location: "Authorization"
}-
-
code: 401
message: "Login Required"
}-
}

Comment: that's a new question. you should ask it in a new thread along with code snippets. it means there is something wrong with the token you've provided, or you haven't provided it in the correct way.